# Swift: How to create a method for parameter that is nil

Tags: swift

How do you create a method that calls on a parameter that is initially set to nil? I'm making my way through the Swift [Guided Tour](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/GuidedTour.playground.zip). I'm getting an error after experimenting with the code in the section about Classes.

As I understand the error, my method `simpleDescription()` is trying to get a value from `numberOfSides` but it is nil, so it causes an error. I tried making the var an optional `var numberOfSides: Int?` but that didn't work. I also tried optional chaining in the method,

```
func simpleDescription() -> String {
        if let checkForNil = self.numberOfSides {
       return "a shape with \(numberOfSides) sides."}
        }
```

but that didn't work either.

**This is the error**

`missing argument for parameter 'numberOfSides' in call super.init(name: name)`

**and the code...**

```
   class NamedShape {
        var numberOfSides: Int
        var name: String

        init(name: String, numberOfSides: Int ) {
           self.name = name
           self.numberOfSides = numberOfSides
        }

        func simpleDescription() -> String {
           return "a shape with \(numberOfSides) sides."}

    }

    var namedShapeOne = NamedShape(name: "My Box", numberOfSides: 6)

    print("\(namedShapeOne.name) is \(namedShapeOne.simpleDescription())")
```

Comment: You full code above (_"and the code" block) looks fine: all class properties are initialized in the init() function. Are you referring to the case _if_ on of your variables were to be an optional (an initialized to value `nil´)?

Comment: From you error it seems as if you called your initializer without a complete conformance with the initializer signature (arguments and external=internal names).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll assume that the case is as I commented above (you code example but your `numberOfSides` property is optional an initialized to `nil`). In that case, you can make use of e.g. the *[nil coalescing operator](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/BasicOperators.html)*:

> The nil coalescing operator (a ?? b) unwraps an optional a if it
>   contains a value, or returns a default value b if a is nil. The
>   expression a is always of an optional type. The expression b must
>   match the type that is stored inside a.

An example on a modified example of your code, making use of the `??` operator:

```
class NamedShape {
    var numberOfSides: Int? = nil
    var name: String

    init(name: String) {
        self.name = name
    }

    func simpleDescription() -> String {
        return "a shape with \(numberOfSides ?? 0) sides."}
}

var namedShapeOne = NamedShape(name: "My Box")

print("\(namedShapeOne.name) is \(namedShapeOne.simpleDescription())")
```

---

Another option is using an `if-let` clause: to unwrap the optional `numberOfSides` and enter the `if` clause if it is not `nil`; otherwise go to the `else` clause

```
class NamedShape {
    var numberOfSides: Int? = nil
    var name: String

    init(name: String) {
        self.name = name
    }

    func simpleDescription() -> String {
        if let a = numberOfSides {
            return "a shape with \(a) sides."}
        else {
            return "a shape with undefined number of sides."
        }
    }
}

var namedShapeOne = NamedShape(name: "My Box")

print("\(namedShapeOne.name) is \(namedShapeOne.simpleDescription())")
```